# List with swiftui which contains objects from object properties

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-foreach

I have a book list on which I manage to act on the sorting according to the section but as soon as I have to access a subcategory of an object like "author" to sort via the name and that this one in contains several (example for a comic: a scriptwriter and a cartoonist), I can't do it. (idem for section kinds)

Can you tell me how to proceed?

Thank you so much

```
List {
    ForEach(viewModel.filter, id: \.self) { section in
            // create a section in terms of filter
        Section {
                // Books sorted by section title
            ForEach(viewModel.arrayBooks, id: \.id) { book in

                if book.title == section {     <---- it's example
                                                     to section title
                    NavigationLink {
                        BookDetailView(book: book)
                    } label: {
                        BookVolumeRow(book: book)
                    }
                }
            }
                //onDelete only works with ForEach
            .onDelete(perform: { indexSet in
                viewModel.deleteRow(indexSet: indexSet)
            })
        }
```

```
var example: [Book] = [
        Book(kinds: [.action, .comedy, .adventure],    <----- problem here, 
                                                              I want the book appear 
                                                              thrice (once by kind)
             title: "My book",
             volume: 8,
             imageName: "Image_Book",
             authors: [Author(name: "John Doe"),       <----- problem here
                       Author(name: "Jeanne Doe")]            I want the book appear 
                                                              twice (once by author)  
             publisher: "BookFab",
             synopsis: "Text description",
             ]
```

```
enum SortFilter: String, CaseIterable, Identifiable {
        //create id for Identifiable
    var id: Self {
            return self
        }

    case title
    case author
    case publisher
    case kind
    case category
}
```

I try to use a loop "forEach" for the authors and kinds but i retrieve only the last item

Comment: viewModel.filter and viewModel.arrayBooks are unknown here so it’s not possible to help you I believe since this seems to be an issue with how your data source is constructed and handled.

Comment: Thanks @JoakimDanielson, I simplified the code, sorry, but for the viewModel.filter, we have an array with the different items (no problem) and arrayBooks contains the Book example provided. I manage to obtain the elements that I want, except for the elements that pose a problem (see message), in which only the last value is taken into account. Example with the authors, I can only display the books of the last author in the array. I'm having a little trouble understanding, I know, sorry.

Comment: Without seeing your actual data source it's hard to help but if you want a book to appear once for each category then I think you will need to have different instances of that book for each category in your datas source